# My program isn't storing the input data into the struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I am currently working on an assignment that takes in a file with student data and outputs the data reformatted into something easy to read.

So how it works right now is that is should open the file, read the data into the structure's different parts, and then print out the data in a tabular format. But I kept running into problems. I modified just to test what was happening and found that I would get something completely different --> it would print an empty variable. What am I doing wrong with how I'm scanning in data?

Input from file
1205,970546325,"Chen","Xiwei",ESE, 230,="R01"

Output
Weird characters that I can't even copy

```
struct student {
    long int term;
    long long int sID;
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[15];
    char subject[3];
    int catalog;
    char section[3];
};

int main(void){
    struct student list[10];
    char fileName[50];
    FILE *inputFile;

    printf("Please enter the name of the file: ");  //get file name
    scanf("%s", &fileName);
    inputFile = fopen(fileName, "r");               //open filelist[i].

    if (inputFile == NULL)
        perror("ERROR");

    int i = 0;
    char test1[150];    

    while (fgets(test1, 150, inputFile) != NULL){       //as long as it's not the EOF, keep reading in the following format
        fscanf(inputFile, "%li*%ll**%^[,]***%^[,]**%^[,]*%i***%s*", 
        &list[i].term, &list[i].sID, &list[i].lastName, &list[i].firstName,
        &list[i].subject, &list[i].catalog, &list[i].section);

        i++;
    }

    printf("Last Name, First Name\t\t\tTerm\tID\t\tCourse\tSection\n");

    printf("%s, %s", list[0].lastName, list[0].firstName);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `sscanf()` on the `test1` variable, not `fscanf()` from your inputfile. Especially not without checking for EOF and how many variables get actually read after you've read the only line the file has with `fgets()`.

Also, your format string is wrong, you cannot use `*` and hope it will skip some characters. Use BLUEPIXY's format. Or, parse the string using strtok:

```
char *p;
while (fgets(test1, 150, inputfile)!=NULL) {
    if ((p=strtok(test1, ","))==NULL) continue;
    list[i].term=atol(p);
    if ((p=strtok(NULL, ","))==NULL) continue;
    list[i].sID=atol(p);
    if ((p=strtok(NULL, ","))==NULL) continue;
    copywithquotes(list[i].lastName, p, 15);
    if ((p=strtok(NULL, ","))==NULL) continue;
    copywithquotes(list[i].firstName, p, 15);
    if ((p=strtok(NULL, ","))==NULL) continue;
    copywithquotes(list[i].subject, p, 3);
    if ((p=strtok(NULL, ","))==NULL) continue;
    list[i].catalog=atoi(p);
    if ((p=strtok(NULL, "\n"))==NULL) continue;
    if (*p=='=')
        p++;
    copywithquotes(list[i].section, p, 3);
    i++;
}

/* copy string from to to. Stop after maxsize bytes. Ignore quotes in the original string */

void copywithquotes(char *to, char *from, int maxsize) {
    int copied=0;
    while (*from && copied<maxsize) {
        while (*from=='"')
            from++;
        *to++=*from++;
        copied++;
    }
    if (copied<maxsize)
        *copied='\0';
}
```

The various `if (strtok...==NULL) continue` lines make the loop ignore non-wellformed input; in a real program, they should probably emit some warning. Also, note that your char[] structure members don't provide space for the '\0' string end markers; better make them 1 byte longer and adjust the last parameter in copywithquotes accordingly
.
The `copywithquotes()` function copies the input strings to the structure, ignoring the quotes that some of your strings have at their beginning and end. (Maybe i should have named it copy**without**quotes, but i was thinking of copying a string that had quotes to something usable).

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more? I tried it just now by replacing the fscanf(...) with sscanf(test1, ...) with the same string format. However it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while (fgets(test1, 150, inputFile) != NULL){
   sscanf(test1, "%ld,%lld,\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\",%3c,%i,=\"%3c\"", 
    &list[i].term, &list[i].sID, list[i].lastName, list[i].firstName,
    list[i].subject, &list[i].catalog, &list[i].section);

    i++;
}
```

side note

```
scanf("%49[^\n]", fileName);
inputFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

if (inputFile == NULL){
    perror("ERROR of fopen");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Changed the format string to allow quotes around the last and first name as specified by the OP.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm  I do not know from his code whether it is necessary.

Comment: Well, his input has quotes around the names, so i guess it's better to remove them, just like the ones around the section. (Since he states it's an assignment, his teacher might have added them as an additional complication to consider in the format string).

Comment: @GuntramBlohm , We are going to change again following the recommendations of you. `*` : It will mean the character probably skip.